# How can I push an new item to an array which is the result of a method?

Tags: php, arrays, initialization, array-push

Here is my code:

```
$this->results['twitter'] = array_push($this->twitter($request),"active");
```

It throws:

> Only variables should be passed by reference

What's wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: `$new_array = $this->twitter($request);   $this->results['twitter'] = array_push($new_array,"active");`

Comment: @JYoThI Thx. Can't I do that in one line, right?

Comment: yes you can't pass the return  result as a  parameter . so you need to store it in variable and pass as a parameter . You can pass a variable by reference to a function so the function can modify the variable

Comment: will you save the array lengh that `array_push` returned in the `$this->results['twitter']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that `array_push` returns an integer representing the count of the array elements after addition. You can use `array_merge` instead:

```
$this->results['twitter'] = array_merge($this->twitter($request), ['active']);
```

Comment: Thank you, upvote. Just what about the order? Will `active` always append in the end of that array?

Comment: the order shouldn't be relevant.. if you really need a way to use that status then just add it a key like: `array_merge($this->twitter($request), ['status' => 'active'])`.. After that you can simply use it like: `$this->results['twitter']['status']`

Answer (score 1):

**1st :** store the result in variable then push

```
$new_array = $this->twitter($request);
$this->results['twitter'] = array_push($new_array,"active");
```

**Note :** yes you can't pass the return result as a parameter . so you need to store it in variable and pass as a parameter . You can pass a variable by reference to a function so the function can modify the variable

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want something like this:

`array_push($this->results['twitter'], $this->twitter());`

This will push the return of the twitter() function into your array.
Beware that array_push only returns the number of the containing items.

Comment: Where is `active`?

Comment: It depends on the array structure you need at the end.

`$newValue[$this->twitter()] = "active";
array_push($this->results['twitter'], $newValue);`